# Adding functionality of identifying custom entities in spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I loaded `en_core_web_lg` model in spacy. Spacy identifies entities like ORG, DATE etc. I trained a custom model to identify custom entities like DRUG etc. But it lose all other functionalities like POS tagging, dependency parsing etc. Is there any other method to include all functionalities of `en_core_web_lg` and also identifying my custom entities.

Here, I loaded the `en_core_web_lg` model like this!

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```